# Page Loading issues during transition between multiple single HTML5 pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I am developing a real estate ipad app using phonegap (using cordova-2.6.js) and jQuery mobile,  which consists of multiple single .html files.

The HTML files are designed using "Twitter CSS Bootstrap Framework" and "Jquery Mobile Framework".

I am facing the following problems:

1. In the case of transitions between two .html pages (For example if I want to go from "index.html" page to "contact.html" page), I am facing page loading issues (In the page, it seems that the css and js files are not loaded properly).
2. In the ipad app, every transition is dependent on ajax base navigation system. If we write the attribute "data-ajax=false", then also the page is not loaded properly.
3. I am not able to call "window.onload" or "bodyonload" event in "contact.html", only document.ready() is working.  For jQuery mobile, we should bind "pageinit" event, but I am not able to do so in "contact.html" page.
4. In "contact.html", $("#form_id").submit( function(){ alert("hello world;")} );  - is not working.

Debugging Issues:

1. Editor used      :  Xcode
2. Operating System :  IOS
3. Technology Stack :  Phonegap, Bootstrap CSS, jQuery Mobile, HTML5

I have used the above mentioned platforms, but I am not able to debug properly in Xcode when these errors occur.  Are there any tools available for Xcode like "Firebug" for "Mozilla Firefox" web browser, such that I can debug jQuery errors from the console?

Comment: You may run into conflicts when you use bootstrap and JQM together,

Comment: are you using modules for ajax and then trigger them with on, pageshow , etc?  also you should move on to single page app if you want to get more performance from jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to develop your app using single page app that includes multiple pages using jQuery Mobile. Its give you more clear and native app like look and feel and also functionality too.

Below your answer to your questions,

1. I think you are using jQuery method to change-page this load only the page but not reload the page instead use window.location.href to load all your css and js files.
2. "data-ajax=false" used for the external page that needs to reload page like typical html page.

and the rest your issues resolved if you develop your app as single page app that contain multiple pages using data-role="page".

And for the debugging like firebug you can use safari browser. there is one tab called Develop in that given one menu item called iPhone Simulator. First run your app using xCode and start safari. its give you the current page name then select that page from safari and its give you same interface like firebug.

Comment: But , this is very large size applications.. So, If we use single page that will not create any problem? Please suggest ....

Answer (score 0):

As Naresh Ramoliya suggested, a single page application is a good answer.

I have made an app using Cordova and Angular JS, it works pretty well and there is no glitches unlike JQuery mobile.

Add Bootstrap on this and you are good to go !